# django-carton cart with two product models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django-catron and I wonder if I can associate two of models as products for my cart? If yes, how?

I have two models: Hall and Caterer and I want them to be my products, which I can insert in my cart (and basically perform any other provided operations).

```
CART_PRODUCT_MODEL = ['marriage_halls.models.Hall', 'marriage_halls.models.Caterer']
```

I tried something like this setting but it gives me error: no attribute 'rsplit'

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried the method I will describe below, but it is worth trying.
Firstly In view.py file, you should do the following additions;

```
from carton.cart import Cart

cart_1 = Cart(session=request.session, session_key = 'CART-1')

cart_2 = Cart(session=request.session, session_key = 'CART-2')
```

Then you could use;

```
cart_1.add(apple, price = 1.5, quantity = 4)

cart_2.add(grapes, price = 2.5, quantity = 3)
```

Hope this method works :)